# How to update role name progammatically in Drupal 8

Tags: users

I am new to Drupal 8. I want to save & update role programmatically in database. I am using below code

```
    //your data array
$data = array('id' => 'client', 'label' => 'Client');
//creating your role
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create($data);
//saving your role
$role->save();
```

It works fine. Now I want update role name. How to proceed it?

Please anyone suggest to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the role object loaded:

```
$role
  ->set('label', 'New label')
  ->save();
```

If you don't:

```
$role = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('user_role')
  ->load('client')
  ->set('label', 'New label')
  ->save();
```